# How to prove these are regular languages

Tags: theory, regular-language

So I have these questions which I need assistance on. I have to prove they are regular languages. I have no idea what DSQ or DF is supposed to be in question 3 and 4. I have the book "Intro to Comp Theory by Spiser" but I have not found anything mentioning DSQ or DF.

1) L = {w....w ∈ Σ*} Σ = {a,b}

2) Trancate(n) = {wa^n  w ∈ Σ* a ∈ Σ |w|=n}

3) DSQ = {a^p, b^p: p prime}

4) DF = {a^n b^n: n > or equal 0}

Comment: It looks like *none* of these are regular. Are you sure you're interpreting the problem right?

Comment: Well I have copied these questions from a class mate and he said to prove these are regular. Maybe he was wrong and you have to prove or disprove? Are these all non-regular languages?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're nonregular. (4) is the canonical example of a nonregular language.

Answer (score 1):

All four of these languages are not regular. There are a couple of different techniques you can use to prove that languages aren't regular. Here's a sampling:

1. Use the [pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). This is the most widely-taught technique for proving that languages aren't regular. You mentioned that you have a copy of Sipser lying around, and he gives a good treatment of the subject in Chapter 1.
2. Use the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1164/lectures/17/Slides17.pdf). This powerful theorem is a little trickier than the pumping lemma to wrap your head around, but does double-duty as a tool for proving languages aren't regular and providing an excellent intuition you can use to sniff out nonregular languages. (This is the technique I teach my students in my introduction to CS theory). The linked slides contain a proof that { a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>n</sup> | n in N } is not regular, both from first principles and using Myhill-Nerode.
3. Use [closure properties of regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties). You can often show that a language is not regular by proving that, after applying a certain operation that maps regular languages to regular languages, you end up with a nonregular language.

Looking over the examples you've provided, I think that the pumping lemma would be the easiest route for proving that language (1) is nonregular. The Myhill-Nerode theorem should make short work of (3) and (4). For (2), you may want to consider taking the intersection of the language and b<sup>☆</sup>a<sup>☆</sup>b<sup>☆</sup>, then apply Myhill-Nerode or the pumping lemma to that resulting language.

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))